# Examples of $C^*$-algebras without strict comparison

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, c-star-algebras, trace

> $\textbf{Definition: }$Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and 
>   $$\mathcal{T}(\mathcal{A})=Tracial~States~of~\mathcal{A}$$ 
>   $\mathcal{A}$ has strict comparison for projections if for all projections $p,q \in \mathcal{A}$
>   $$\tau({p})<\tau(q)~~~~~~\forall~\tau \in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{A}) \implies p\leq q$$

I am trying to find a $C^*$-algebra which does not have strict comparison for projections. I want to find a simple , unital AF algebra without strict comparison that is

$\textbf{GOAL:}~~~~~$Find a simple unital AF-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $p,q \in \mathcal{A}$ projections such that $\tau(p)=\tau(q)$ for all $\tau \in \mathcal{T}(\mathcal{A})$ but $p \not\sim q$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What does $p \leq q$ mean in this context?

Comment: And what does $p \sim q$ mean?

Comment: $p \leq q$ means $pq=qp=p$ and $p \sim q$ is murray von equivalance of projections, that is $p \sim q $ if  and only if there exist a partial isometry $v$ such that $v^*v=p$ and $vv^*=q$.

Comment: The title is misleading since you are not asking for strict comparison in your question.

Comment: Please do read the whole problem @Epsilon